# reflection coefficient derivation for normal incidence emr

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, reflection, boundary-conditions

Starting with the boundary conditions for parallel E and B fields for emr normal to an interface, i am trying to derive reflection coefficient with refractive indices.
 I have got as far as

> $E_1=E_2\qquad \qquad $       (parallel $\vec E$ fields are equal)
>
> $E_{0i}+E_{0r}=E_{0t}\qquad \qquad $     Eq.(a)
>
> $\frac{B_1}{\mu_1} = \frac{B_2}{\mu_2}\qquad \qquad  $     (parallel $\vec B$ fields are discontinuous)
>
> $\frac{E_i}{\mu_0  v_1} + \frac{E_{0r}}{\mu_0 v_1} = 
> \frac{E_{0t}}{\mu_0 v_1} \qquad $       (B fields represented as
>   electric field by dividing through by speed)
>
> $E_{0i}-E_{0r} = \frac{v1}{v2} E_{0t} \qquad $
>   (cancel $\mu_0$ and multiply by $v_1$)
>
> $E_{0i}-E_{0r} = \frac{n_2}{n_1}  E_{0t} \qquad $       Eq. (b)
>   (can swap $v$ for refractive
>   index)
>
> $2E_{0i}=\left(1+\frac{n_2}{n_1} E_{0t}\right)\qquad $   Eq.(c)      (I can the get to here by adding equation a and b together)

I know I'm really close but I can't quite get to the reflection or transmission coefficient, how can i finish this off?

[image: derivation]

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: ok done that, still stuck :(

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: For starters you can rearrange Eq.(c) to $\frac{2 n_1}{n_1+n_2}E_{0i}=E_{0t}$ by multiplying both sides by $n_1$.  The transmission coefficients are usually expressed in terms of $E_{0i}$ so I suspect your bottom right is slightly incorrect.

Comment: Your equation involving the B-field is incorrect.

Comment: how so? i dont think so. total parrallel B field at a surface are discontinuos by their charge densities, can covert that to E by dividing by the speed. where does it go wrong?